# SQL Question on creating table from two others

Tags: sql, plsql

I have one table with a single column of dates that go back every day for 10 years.  I have a 2nd table with one column of string names. How can I create a table with all 10 years of dates for each string in the 2nd column?

Ex.

Here are some dates from first table:

```
01/02/2001
01/03/2001
01/04/2001 
...
```

Here are some strings from the 2nd table:

```
'Jim'
'Joe'
'Wil'
'Tom'
```

I am looking to create a 3rd table with a row for every date for every person - like this:

```
Jim, 01/02/2001
Jim, 01/03/2001
Jim, 01/04/2001
Joe, 01/02/2001
Joe, 01/03/2001
Joe, 01/04/2001
Wil, 01/02/2001
Wil, 01/03/2001
Wil, 01/04/2001
Tom, 01/02/2001
Tom, 01/03/2001
Tom, 01/04/2001
```

Comment: Looks like a CROSS JOIN. But you shouldn't store same values in different places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a Cartesian product, use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select *
from dates d cross join
     names n;
```